# Image map in Chrome: events are not firing! Works fine in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome, dictionary

I have an image with a set of areas mapped to it. Each area, when clicked will call a function to do something. This whole ordeal works great in IE7! For once, it's Chrome that is hassling me. Chrome will not fire ANY event over these areas, and I can not pinpoint the problem. Here is relevant code:

```
<div id="containerRemote">
<img src="resources/buttons/RC64_small.png" width="170" height="590"
alt="" usemap="#remotemap" />
<map id="remotemap" name="remotemap">
    <area shape="circle" coords="37,47.5,12" alt="TV Input" />
    <area shape="circle" id="format" coords="37,78.5,12.5" alt="Format" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="85.5,60.5,13" alt="Power" />
    <area shape="circle" id="poweron" coords="140.5,50.5,12.5" alt="DTV Power On" />
    <area shape="circle" id="poweroff" coords="140.5,79.5,12" alt="DTV Power Off" />
    <area shape="circle" id="play" coords="87.5,134,17" alt="Play" />
    <area shape="circle" id="stop" coords="87.5,95.5,13" alt="Stop" />
    <area shape="circle" id="rewind" coords="43,134,14" alt="Rewind" />
    <area shape="circle" id="fastforward" coords="133.5,134,14" alt="Fast Forward" />
    <area shape="circle" id="pause" coords="61.5,164.5,13" alt="Pause" />
    <area shape="circle" id="record" coords="116,162.5,13" alt="Record" />
    <area shape="circle" id="replay" coords="61.5,101.5,13" alt="Replay" />
    <area shape="circle" id="advance" coords="116,105,13" alt="Advance" />
    <area shape="circle" id="guide" coords="40.5,205.5,15" alt="Guide" />
    <area shape="circle" id="active" coords="68.5,187.5,17" alt="Active" />
    <area shape="circle" id="list" coords="106.5,187.5,14" alt="List" />
    <area shape="circle" id="exit" coords="133.5,209,15" alt="Exit" />
    <area shape="circle" id="select" coords="89,243.5,18" alt="Select" />
    <area shape="circle" id="up" coords="89,209,12.5" alt="Up" />
    <area shape="circle" id="up2" coords="73.5,211.5,12.5" alt="Up" />
    <area shape="circle" id="up3" coords="104.5,211.5,12.5" alt="Up" />
    <area shape="circle" id="down" coords="89,279,12.5" alt="Down" />
    <area shape="circle" id="down2" coords="73.5,271.5,12.5" alt="Down" />
    <area shape="circle" id="down3" coords="104.5,271.5,12.5" alt="Down" />
    <area shape="circle" id="left" coords="53.5,243.5,12.5" alt="Left" />
    <area shape="circle" id="left2" coords="56,224.5,12.5" alt="Left" />
    <area shape="circle" id="left3" coords="53.5,257,12.5" alt="Left" />
    <area shape="circle" id="right" coords="122.5,243.5,12.5" alt="Right" />
    <area shape="circle" id="right2" coords="121,224.5,12.5" alt="Right" />
    <area shape="circle" id="right3" coords="119.5,257,12.5" alt="Right" />
    <area shape="circle" id="back" coords="40.5,288,15" alt="Back" />
    <area shape="circle" id="menu" coords="86.5,305,17" alt="Menu" />
    <area shape="circle" id="info" coords="133.5,290,15" alt="Info" />
    <area shape="circle" id="red" coords="45,320,12" alt="Red" />
    <area shape="circle" id="green" coords="70.5,334.5,12" alt="Green" />
    <area shape="circle" id="yellow" coords="100,334.5,12" alt="Yellow" />
    <area shape="circle" id="blue" coords="125,320,12" alt="Blue" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="47,356,15" alt="Volume Plus" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="51,399.5,14" alt="Volume Minus" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="49,428.5,12" alt="Mute" />
    <area shape="circle" id="channelup" coords="130.5, 356.5,15" alt="Channel Plus" />
    <area shape="circle" id="channeldown" coords="127.5,399,14" alt="Channel Minus" />
    <area shape="circle" id="previous" coords="126.5,428.5,12" alt="Previous Channel" />
    <area shape="circle" id="one" coords="49,456.5,12" alt="One" />
    <area shape="circle" id="two" coords="87.5,456.5,12" alt="Two" />
    <area shape="circle" id="three" coords="125,456.5,12" alt="Three" />
    <area shape="circle" id="four" coords="49,486.5,12" alt="Four" />
    <area shape="circle" id="five" coords="87.5,486.5,12" alt="Five" />
    <area shape="circle" id="six" coords="125,486.5,12" alt="Six" />
    <area shape="circle" id="seven" coords="49,513.5,12" alt="Seven" />
    <area shape="circle" id="eight" coords="87.5,513.5,12" alt="Eight" />
    <area shape="circle" id="nine" coords="125,513.5,12" alt="Nine" />
    <area shape="circle" id="dash" coords="49,539.5,12" alt="Dash" />
    <area shape="circle" id="zero" coords="87.5,539.5,12" alt="Zero" />
    <area shape="circle" id="enter" coords="125,539.5,12" alt="Enter" />
</map>
</div>
```

I don't like barraging you with this huge list of map areas, but it's possible that there is some error within the map that I'm missing. Here is the JS that binds function calls to onclick events on these areas. Below is also a piece of JQuery code that I added which assigns an href attribute to each area mapping.

```
    $("#remotemap area").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") != undefined) {
        logRCCommand($(this).attr("id"));
    }
    return false;
});

    $("#remotemap area").attr("href", "javascript: void(0);");
```

CSS:

```
#containerRemote{
position: absolute; /* this line, when commented, fixes the problem, but ruins layout         */
width: 170px; 
}
```

Interestingly enough, at the very bottom of the image are three areas that work just fine, although their size is incorrect. This leads me to believe that I have some sort of formatting error as opposed to a syntax or logic error. Even still, I don't know what would be causing this. I scoured the internet for clues, but to no avail!

Thanks

Update: I think the problem has something to do with CSS. I commented out a certain line of CSS for the div that this map is contained within. Voila! Everything works fine, but now the layout of the entire page has gone to hell. I don't know if this should be a new question or just an update of the current one. In any case I updated my code to include even more relevant lines.

Comment: Well your code is invalid since you have multiple elements with the same id, that is not allowed. ids are singular. Use HTML 5 data attribute data-id.

Comment: @epascarello I updated my code to reflect your comment, although I did not use the data-id attribute. Instead I simply made the id's unique. This does not fix the problem, although I thank you for catching my mistake which may have caused other issues down the road.

Comment: Downvote without a comment explaining the reason? +1 to undo.

Comment: I copy/pasted this in a page, changed the call to `logRCCommand` to an `alert`, and it fires fine in Chrome (and Firefox) for me

Comment: @Rodolfo I've come to the conclusion that this issue has something to do with CSS. I bound an alert to a mouseover event on the div which contains the image map. The alert only pops up on the bottom tenth of the image. When I comment out the "position: relative;" style in the CSS related to the div (given above). The events fire properly and the areas are properly mapped. Unfortunately, this ruins the layout of my page.

Comment: @dr7164 but I copied the whole thing you posted, CSS and all, to my page and my alert fires fine.  Didn't see any 'position: relative' anywhere though, just 'position:absolute' in `#containerRemote`.  Maybe you have something else invisible covering part of the image?

Comment: Yes, yes. I apologize. Due to the amount of HTML and CSS related to my issue, I've omitted a lot. While the above code does indeed work just fine on its own, when combined with other styled divs, my problems arise. I am not sure whether to start a new question as the scope of this one has widened and changed or to truck on and include more information. I will include more code which is relevant to the issue.

Comment: @dr7164, do you have a try without the jquery code? And, the following code could work for me ( with Chromium 18.0.1025.151 Ubuntu 10.04):
    <area shape="circle" id="tv" onclick='alert("TV Input");' coords="37,47.5,12" alt="TV Input"/>

Comment: @Rodolfo I figured out my issue thanks to your advice, see my answer below!

Comment: @Sanders I thought it could've been a JQuery issue as well, but it ended being a silly CSS oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rodolfo's comment, I was able to figure out that a separate div ADJACENT to my image map was wider than I thought, and a portion of it (a portion which had no content, making that part invisible) was covering my image map, rendering it practically unusable, except for the small fraction of it that was not covered by the div.

I don't understand how the other div came to be so wide, but that is something for me to figure out later when I have time :P

Anyways, I changed the z-index of the div containing my image map

```
#containerRemote {
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

Everything works fine now! My problem was not one of Chrome not firing the event, but a difference between Chrome's layout of the content and IE7's layout.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add href attributes to all of the area elements

```
<area shape="circle" coords="37,47.5,12" alt="TV Input" href="#" />
```

Comment: I have a piece of JQuery which assigns the href attribute to each area mapping. Please note my edited post with that line of code newly added. Also, I tried manually adding the href attribute to each tag, in case the JQuery was the problem. Neither of these solutions are providing a fix.